# how to show the header and footer in the subreport in SSRS report.i have a subreport in the list.

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

how to show the header and footer in the subreport in SSRS report.i have a subreport in the list.
sub report contains header and footer. but it's not showing it's showing only a content.

Answer (score 6):

It is not possible to display a page header/footer of a subreport, only the body.

This is limited by design.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried with SSRS 2008 R2. It works for me. Please give more detail ( version ,screenshot...)

[image: Sub Report]

[image: Report Sample]

Comment: These are elements in the report body, not the header/footer